# Creating filtered lookup in SharePoint 2010 with InfoPath 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath, lookup-column, filter

I have a requirement similar to this. 
https://www.sharepointusecases.com/2010/01/creating-filtered-lookups-in-sharepoint-2010-with-infopath-2010/

In my case Project field should be a text field and auto populated based on "TRUE" OR "FALSE" value.
So what I have done was created similar InfoPath form and additionally created one field for "TRUE" OR "FALSE" and one field for Project text field.
I set a rule to Project dropdown field, when Project dropdown field changes set Project text field value. Problem is **only** when I select Project dropdown field, project dropdown value is loading. Otherwise project dropdown value is not loading. Any guessing what's going wrong?

Comment: please clarify more the last section of your question

Comment: I have to select project dropdown to load my project textbox value. I'm looking why project textbox is not loading without touching project dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At what point are you quering you data connection do you get your dropdown data? On the rule change or onload?

It should be loaded onload. (in anyway before selecting dropdown)